# Linking two Handsontables

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I'm trying to link two Handsontables so that the second table shows additional details for the current column in the first table. The number in the column header of the first table would be used to find the corresponding row in the second table.

Clicking on any cell in the first table should cause the corresponding row in the second table to be highlighted.

Clicking in the second table should highlight that row and move the cursor in the first table to the corresponding column.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="main" class="handsontable"></div>
<p>
<div id="index" class="handsontable"></div>
```

And here's the Javascript to display the tables:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function getMainData() {
    return [["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13], ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13], ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]];
}

function getMainHeaders() {
    return ["Year", 1, 2, 3, 4];
}

function getIndexData() {
    return [[1, "Kia", "Korea"], [2, "Nissan", "Japan"], [3, "Toyota", "Japan"], [4, "Honda", "Japan"]];
}

function getIndexHeaders() {
    return ["#", "Make", "Country"];
}

$("#main").handsontable({
    data: getMainData(),
    colHeaders: getMainHeaders(),
    fillHandle: false,
    readOnly: true
});

$("#index").handsontable({
    data: getIndexData(),
    colHeaders: getIndexHeaders(),
    fillHandle: false,
    readOnly: true        
});

});
```

All I need is the code to link the tables! I've gone around in circles trying to make this work, but no joy.

I've got all of the above in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ltoews/2b2JU/).

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do what you asked about [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/2b2JU/8/). I added this code after the initiation of the tables:

```
var sync = function(tab1, tab2) {
    var syncSelection = function(row, col, rowEnd, colEnd) {
        var sel1 = tab1.getSelected();
        var sel2 = tab2.getSelected();
        if (!sel2) {
            tab2.selectCell(row, col, rowEnd, colEnd);
            return;
        }
        for (var key in sel1) {
            if (sel1[key] !== sel2[key]) {
                tab2.selectCell(row, col, rowEnd, colEnd);
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    // syncs while selecting (does not work for selecting one cell)
    tab1.addHook('afterSelection', syncSelection);
    // needed to sync selection of one cell
    tab1.addHook('afterSelectionEnd', syncSelection);
};


var mainTable = $('#main').handsontable('getInstance');
var indexTable = $('#index').handsontable('getInstance');

sync(mainTable, indexTable);
sync(indexTable, mainTable);
```

Comment: I see now that you wanted different behaviour depending on which table you select from. Hopefully you can use my answer and adapt it to work the way you wanted.